# How to contrl gap between components, e.g. Buttons

Tags: codenameone

Recent apk generated by the compile server, found the gap between components (buttons) is becoming larger, how to control it? I am using GridLayout, to layout components.

Previous compiled is nice, but recent compile is changed.

Answer (score 0):

This specific change was [mentioned here](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/pixel-perfect-material-buttons-part-2.html).

You will see it in the simulator if you update your simulator skin (under skins -> more). I'm assuming the margin of the buttons is the problem for your design.